# Why does kafka consumer poll the broker?

Tags: apache-kafka

Currently learning about Kafka architecture and I'm confused as to why the consumer polls the broker. Why wouldn't the consumer simply subscribe to the broker and supply some callback information and wait for the broker to get a record? Then when the broker gets a relevant record, look up who needs to know about it and look at the callback information to dispatch the messages? This would reduce the number of network operations hugely.

Comment: The broker is dumb. It should not be responsible for discovering clients and maintaining outgoing network requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka can be used as a messaging service, but it is not the only possible usecase. You could also treat it as a remote *file* that can have bytes (records) read on demand.

Also, if notification mechanism were to implemented in message-broker fashion as you suggest, you'd need to handle slow consumers. Kafka leaves all control to consumers, allowing them to consume at their own speed.